# Creating hovering info for two columns using css

Tags: html, css, hover, multiple-columns

I'm using php to generate links and then im using css to put them into 2 columns. Also when the user hovers over a link extra info is shown like the title attribute. This all works fine except when i hover over something in the second column the extra info isn't shown. 
This is my css code:

```
#pantherGal{
    position:relative;
    height:667px;
    width:840px;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
    top:-1269px;
    left:-850px;
    padding-left:10px;
    overflow:auto;
    color:#393;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:x-large;
    column-count:2; 
    -moz-column-count:2; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-column-count:2; /* Safari and Chrome */
}
a.tip:hover {
    position: relative;
}
a.tip span {
   display: none
}
a.tip:hover span {
    position:relative;
    padding:5px 20px 5px 5px;
    display:block;
    z-index:100;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
    color:#393;
    margin-left:10px;
    width:250px;
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
}
```

the links are generated in a section with the id pantherGal and then the link html looks like this

```
<a href="#" class="tip"><span>Extra<br>Info</span>This Is A Link With Extra Info</a><br>
```

Comment: What is the second column you are referring to? Here is your code as-is right now: http://jsfiddle.net/95CrM/

Comment: Sorry their are 50 links like this http://jsfiddle.net/cmbasse/sHpBG/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the position:absolute in the class

`a.tip:hover span` and now its woking..

Comment: Wow i didn't even see that until you pointed it out thanks for the help